# Inverses of bijective functions.

Tags: functions

Whenever I see a $1-1$  and onto function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$,I wonder how do I even go about finding the inverse.

> Is there a general way of finding the inverse of a bijective function  $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? Or is it really possible that inverse of all bijective functions can be written down as a formula?

Comment: No, it depends on the expression of $f(x)$. simple or complicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an uncountable number of bijections on $\mathbb{R}$, and only a countable set of "formulas" consisting of finite strings of mathematical symbols from some (finite) alphabet. Therefore, by the pigeonhole principle, there are bijections on $\mathbb{R}$ where no formula (with any set of finite mathematical symbols) exists. Thus, there can be no general algorithm for finding inverses of bijections on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your argument seems very interesting!(+1) I get it that there are an uncountable number of bijections. Can you convince me a little more on the second part.. that there can only be a countable set of formulas.

Comment: Imagine I have $n$ letters in my mathematical alphabet. Ascribe to each letter a number between $0$ and $n-1$. Read the formula from left to right and write down the number for each symbol. This number corresponds to a positive integer written in base $n$. Thus, the set of all formulas can be put into one-to-one correspondence to the positive integers, making them countable.